# "defer" for whole package in GoLang

Tags: go

Is there a way in to "defer" some function in a package so that it runs no matter what when the program that imported it terminates, it runs?

```
package something

import "fmt"

defer fmt.Println("package defer")
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "something"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("main")
    defer fmt.Println("function defer")
    // Desired output
    // main
    // function defer
    // package defer
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. When main() returns, the program exits.

Comment: @PaulHankin could maybe something like launching a goroutine from the package's `init` function that is listening to some event, like sigkill or somesuch thingy, do the job? I don't know though if there's an event for `main`'s plain exit, probably not.

Comment: @mkopriva When main() returns, the program exits. It doesn't matter what goroutines you have started or what they are doing. You need to have an explicit call like `defer something.Cleanup()` from main to make sure it gets executed.